# NSUserDefaults for in-app purchase variables?

Tags: iphone, variables, encryption, in-app-purchase, nsuserdefaults

Within my app I've been storing variables in the NSUserDefaults, these variables are increased by in-app purchases within the app. My question is whether when the app is updated will these variables will remain so that the user can still access them after the update.

Additionally what's the best practice for storing variables of this sort; what do Apple recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSUserDefaults data doesn’t get removed between app updates unless the user uninstalls and reinstalls the app. It also gets stored in backups (both via iTunes and iCloud), so as long as the user has one of those set up and doesn’t uninstall the app, you can rely on the data persisting.

As a side note, you should probably be encrypting the values you store in the defaults—the file is user-accessible, which makes it possible to tamper with.

Comment: How would the user be able to access the UserDefaults? - I understand they could if they had a Jail Broken device.

Comment: Altering the contents of a backup would be one way. Tools that allow access to the user’s home folder on the device (which don’t require jailbreaking) would be another, though I haven’t tried that myself.

Comment: I've never heard of that happening however what method would you recommend for encrypting the variables?

Comment: You could do something simple like storing a salted hash of a string formed by concatenating the values and then verifying that checksum before using the values loaded from the defaults. You could also use AES (or similar) to encrypt the data formed by serializing a dictionary holding your values… but that might be overkill for this case.

Answer (score 1):

They will remain after an update but if the user deletes the app completely, restarts the OS or gets a new phone they will be erased or not exist so I would think that's not a good solution to rely on for anything important.

Comment: It's not desperately important but I just wanted to ensure that after something like a small update that it wouldn't get rid of all the variables.

Comment: Ok well in that case you should be fine. If you want something to persist for the user you'd have to have a user account of some form or rely on the in app purchase system.